# ¿Como mover el punto decimal hacia la izquierda n espacios con Jquery o JS?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tengo el siguiente código:

```
 $('#txtFederalCantidad').mask('00000000', { reverse: true });
                    valorFederal = $('#txtFederalCantidad').val(); 
                    $('#txtMonto').mask('00000000', { reverse: true });
                    var Monto = $('#txtMonto').val();
                    var Total = (valorFederal / Monto) * 100;
                    var TotalMostrar = Total.toFixed(2);
                    $('#txtFederalCantidad').mask('00.00', { reverse: true });         
                    $('#txtFederalCantidad').val(TotalMostrar);
```

Supongamos que la variable "TotalMostrar" tiene como resultado 1658.99, ¿Cómo puedo recorrer el punto decimal para que aparezca como 16.5899?

Comment: dividiendo entre 100

Comment: o cambiando la máscara a `00.0000`?

Comment: Falta que indiques lo que has intentado, buscado/investigado. Referencia [ask].

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Para correr el punto decimal, solo debes de multiplicar o dividir entre un múltipo de 10.

1. Para correr el punto a la derecha multiplicas.
2. Para correr el punto a la izquierda divides.

Asumiendo que *TotalMostrar* es 1658.99

**Punto para la izquierda**

```
var TotalMostrar = 1658.99;
TotalMostrar /= 100;
//TotalMostrar ahora es igual a 16.5899
```

**Punto para la derecha**

```
var TotalMostrar = 1658.99;
TotalMostrar *= 10;
//TotalMostrar ahora es igual a 16589.9
```

Ahora bien, para determinar la cantidad de espacios, como dices en la pregunta, lo que debes de hacer es elevar 10 a la n. Para esto puedes usar `Math.pow()` (más información [aquí](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Math/pow))

```
var n = 2;
var exponente = Math.pow(10, n);
var TotalMostrar = 1658.99;
TotalMostrar /= exponente;
```

Comment: Correcto, lo estaba complicando haciendo un substring, gracias ;).

Comment: Un placer, me alegra haberte ayudado.